# Is there a way to integrate the contributions/commits from Azure DevOps to GitHub?

Tags: azure, github, azure-devops, devops

In the past 6 months I've been working with Azure DevOps. Due to that, my GitHub contributions chart looks a bit empty.

I would like to integrate all of my contributions from Azure DevOps to Github's contributions chart.

I did some research, browsed for different extensions/APis. Though there are plenty out there, it didn't seem like they covered what I wanted to achieve.

Is this possible? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all,  you should understand that GitHub and Azure DevOps are independent systems. Azure DevOps has provided some functions e.g REST API, extensions to get repository from GitHub. But It’s a one-way data transfer from GitHub to Azure DevOps.

There is no supported REST API or extensions that can sync commits from Azure DevOps to your GitHub according DevOps documents at present.

I'm afraid that you could only sync contributions/commits manually.

If  you want GitHub contributions chart logged your activity, you should make commits in GitHub.